# checkedListBox, стиль шрифта

Tags: c#, winforms

Как изменить в `checkedListBox` стиль шрифта для отдельно взятого элемента?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это придётся делать вручную.
К сожалению, свойство `DrawMode` и событие `DrawItem` скрыты у `CheckedListBox`. Обойти это можно, создав класс-наследник:

```
public class CustomCheckedListBox : CheckedListBox
{
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(e);

        if (e.Index == 1)
        {
            TextRenderer.DrawText(
                e.Graphics,
                Items[e.Index].ToString(),
                new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Italic), // задаем желаемый шрифт
                new Point(e.Bounds.X + e.Bounds.Height + 1, e.Bounds.Y + 1),
                e.ForeColor,
                e.BackColor,
                TextFormatFlags.Left);
        }
    }
}
```

Перепробовав разные способы, я остановился на таком довольно простом. Вызов метода `base.OnDrawItem` обеспечивает правильную прорисовку чекбокса, фона и фокуса.

После чего вручную выводим текст желаемым шрифтом. Используем класс `TextRenderer` - его метод `DrawText` имеет перегрузку, принимающую цвет фона. При этом закрашивается ранее выведенный текст, и поверх него выводится текст нашим шрифтом.

Добавьте в этот класс свойства, задавая которые можно будет указывать индекс(ы) элементов, у которого(ых) нужно изменить шрифт.

P.S. Желательно диспозить создаваемый шрифт, либо сделать его полем класса.